# Trim/Crop specified text from both sides

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I need to crop and display specified keyword(with some words around) from possibly long text.

So imagine a text like:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua

keyword:

> iscing

My goal is to display in some TextBlock with very limited width something like:

> consectetur adip**iscing** elit

or (better)

> ...consectetur adip**iscing** elit...

number of words around the keyword should be based on a space available.

We use the MVVM pattern. Does anybody have a working solution for that? Thanks a lot

EDIT: I do not want to highlight the keyword right now.

EDIT 2: For the sake of simplicity assume that we want to display only the first occurrence of the "iscing" keyword.

Edit 3: To get it clear again - imagine you have some large text in application (document) and other component of appplication like TextBlock displaying the searched keyword from large text with some words around so the user can get the context. The Textblock can be resized at runtime so it should display more words (based on the size). Keyword should ideally stay somewhere in the middle of the Textblock.

Comment: What if `iscing` exists in several occurrences in the text?

Comment: It is not about trimming!

Comment: It might be possible to achieve this, stay tuned.

Comment: Reasons for downvoting? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function do what you ask:

```
public string Truncate(string input, string match, int nbCharMaxBefore, int nbCharMaxAfter)
{  
    var inputSplit = input.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var index = 0;
    while (index < inputSplit.Length)
    {
        if (inputSplit[index].Contains(match)) break;

        index++;
    }

    if (index == inputSplit.Length)
    {
        // No match
        return String.Empty;
    }

    // Adds all the words before the match as long as the sum of all the words is not greater than the specified limit
    var previousWords = new List<string>();
    var i = index - 1;
    while (i >= 0)
    {
        var previousWord = inputSplit[i];

        if (previousWord.Length + previousWords.Sum(w => w.Length) < nbCharMaxBefore)
        {
            previousWords.Insert(0, previousWord);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        i--;
    }

    // Adds all the words after the match as long as the sum of all the words is not greater than the specified limit
    var nextWords = new List<string>();
    i = index + 1;
    while (i < inputSplit.Length)
    {
        var nextWord = inputSplit[i].TrimEnd(',');

        if (nextWord.Length + nextWords.Sum(w => w.Length) < nbCharMaxAfter)
        {
            nextWords.Add(nextWord);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    var prev = String.Join(" ", previousWords);
    var next = String.Join(" ", nextWords);

    return $"...{prev} {inputSplit[index]} {next}...";
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
var input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua";
var match = "iscing";
var nbCharMaxBefore = 15;
var nbCharMaxAfter = 5;

var truncatedStr = Truncate(input, match, nbCharBefore, nbCharAfter); // ...consectetur adipiscing elit...
```

Concerning the MVVM way, considering the property you are binding on is `MyText`, just bind on another property like that:

```
public string MyTruncatedText
{
    get { return Truncate(this.MyText, this.MyMatch, this.NbCharBefore, this.NbCharAfter); }
}
```

Finally, in the setter of `MyText`, you want to call `NotifyPropertyChanges(nameof(MyTruncatedProperty))` or the equivalent in your MVVM toolkit.

Comment: I do not believe actual string processing is the problem here, nor will your solution achieve the bold text since it is all in one string.

Comment: That's true, my solution does not achieve the bold text. But the OP does not ask for it (well .. not directly ^^). He ask for cropping his text.

Comment: Right, I did not ask for the bold text or the highlighting (thats the part I've done already). Sorry for misunderstood.

Comment: This actually works, but I hoped that there is some better solution, this computes with hardcoded counts of char before/after so it will not work when the textblock gets more space (gridsplitter etc.). It can also crops a part of the word, which is something I cannot accept.

Comment: How can the function crops a part of the word? You may be are right, but I can't find values that reproduce that. Concerning the `NbCharBefore` and `NbCharAfter`, they are just function parameters. It is up to you to compute them according to the textblock size.

Comment: Cause they crops chars, not the whole words - it will look weird if the content of the textblock will look like ''...etur adipiscing elit..." instead of "consectetur adipiscing elit...".

Comment: I just edited the function: Given a maximum number of char before and after, it crops the input by words. It is a little bit longer than the previous one but do the job as you want.

Comment: Perfect. I am going to do some behavior for TextBlock with text highlighting and cropping around highlighted text. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Databind following textblock to appropriate properties.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run x:Name="pre" Text="{Binding PrecedingText}" />
    <Run x:Name="search" Text="{Binding SearchText}" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <Run x:Name="succeeding" Text="{Binding SucceedingText}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Use the following view model class.

```
class SearchResult
{
      public PrecedingText { get; set; }
      public SearchText { get; set; }
      public SucceedingText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to display the whole Preceding and Succeeding text. The goal is to display the SearchText always and some words around it, the number of others words around should be based on available space of Textblock (can be modified by GridSplitter at runtime).

Comment: Imagine you have some large text in application (document) and other component of appplication like TextBlock displaying the searched keyword (user input) from large text with some words around so the user can get the context of the keyword.